# Cannot insert values into my SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

This is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Veiculos] 
(
    [IDCar]      INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Matricula]  VARCHAR (8)  NOT NULL,
    [Marca]      VARCHAR (30) NULL,
    [Modelo]     VARCHAR (30) NULL,
    [Cor]        VARCHAR (15) NULL,
    [Cilindrada] INT          NULL,
    [Estado]     CHAR (1)     NULL,
    [Preco]      MONEY        NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDCar] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Matricula] ASC),
    CHECK ([Estado]='Usado' OR [Estado]='Novo')
);
```

For some reason, whenever I try to add values directly into the table it gives me the following error :

> "The data in row 1 was not committed
>   Error Source: .Net SqlCliente Data Provider.
>   Error Message: String or binary data would be truncated."

[image: Error Example]

This is for a college project, I'm still a novice with SQL, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Share your insert query.

Comment: How many chars long is 'Estado' in your insert and how many chars is the field on the table?

Comment: you are setting the legth of Estado to 1 char long. So it wont take anything longer.  Also your ID should not be null. you might  want to add the autoincrement

Comment: @MadeInDreams it is an identity, so you would not insert a value.

Comment: Yes but it cant be null

Comment: I usualy create the ID field like that; id INT(8) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

Comment: @dfundako Yup that was it mate.

Comment: @MadeInDreams I set it as an auto increment, that one value is not NULL.   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`estado` is defined as `char(1)`, but you are trying to put the value `'Novo'`.

Either put in a single character or redefine the column width.  Given your `check` constraint, you probably want `estado` defined as `varchar(10)` or something:

```
alter table [dbo].[Veiculos] alter column estado varchar(10);
```

Comment: That one did the trick. I thought I needed to use "char 1" as it is an option novo (new) or usado (used).Thank you very much mate.

Answer (score 0):

One of your fields is not big enough to hold the data. check the length of strings or int values are bigger than the range allowed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

I see two things

```
IDCar need to have a value
```

and

```
[Estado]     CHAR (1)
```

but the value you are trying to enter is of length 4. Try yo update it in the following way

```
[Estado]     CHAR (4)
```